# Creating a list with jQuery

Tags: jquery, list

I'm trying to create a comma separated list of data-value's where the tag also has a class of 'btn-darkgrey'. I've tried using the map function but I can't gt it to work. would this be the right was to do it?

```
<input type="hidden" id="AmenitiesType" name="Amenities"/>
<div class="col-s-2">
     <a href="#" class="btn-default AmenitiesOption" data-value="Breakfast Included">Breakfast Included</a>
</div>
<div class="col-s-2">
     <a href="##" class="btn-darkgrey AmenitiesOption" data-value="Smoking">Smoking</a>
</div>
<div class="col-s-2">
     <a href="##" class="btn-darkgrey AmenitiesOption" data-value="Non-smoking">Non-smoking</a>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var list_container = $("#AmenitiesType");
    var amenity_value = $('.AmenitiesOption').hasClass( "btn-darkgrey" ).map(function(){
    return this.data('value');
}).get();
list_container.val(amenity_value.join(','));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do it like this

```
var list_container = $("#AmenitiesType");
list_container.val($('.AmenitiesOption.btn-darkgrey[data-value]').map(function(){
   return $(this).data("value");
}).get().join(","));
```

Comment: I don't know what you're meaning. My edit should clear out things

Comment: @JamesPrivett glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is a bit off, `hasClass` returns a boolean, you simply want:

```
$('.AmenitiesOption.btn-darkgrey').map
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , see output for varification

```js
var list_container = $("#AmenitiesType");
    var amenity_value = $('.AmenitiesOption.btn-darkgrey').map(function(){
    return $(this).data('value');
}).get();
console.log(amenity_value);
list_container.val(amenity_value.join(','));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="AmenitiesType" name="Amenities"/>
<div class="col-s-2">
     <a href="#" class="btn-default AmenitiesOption" data-value="Breakfast Included">Breakfast Included</a>
</div>
<div class="col-s-2">
     <a href="##" class="btn-darkgrey AmenitiesOption" data-value="Smoking">Smoking</a>
</div>
<div class="col-s-2">
     <a href="##" class="btn-darkgrey AmenitiesOption" data-value="Non-smoking">Non-smoking</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This,

```
var list_container = $("#AmenitiesType");
var amenity_value = $('.AmenitiesOption.btn-darkgrey').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('data-value');
}).get();

list_container.val(amenity_value.join(','));
```

Comment: As tymeJV said in his answer [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) returns a boolean, it doesn't filter. Also attr isn't a method on vanilla javascript objects